# Random Walk to a Time Series in R

Tags: r, random-walk, holtwinters

I am trying to answer the following question"

> The time series given below gives the price of a dozen eggs in cents, adjusted for inflation.  Fit a random walk to the time series egg.ts.  What is the SS1PE?

```
library(tsdl)
eggs.ts <- tsdl[[440]]
```

I am stuck on how I fit a random walk to the time series. I know how to fit a general random walk using `rnorm` but not to a specific time series.  There is a second part to this question below.

> Modify your fit above to fit a random walk with a Holt-Winters slope term as well to the eggs time series.  Compute the SS1PE.  Is this a better fit than the random walk without the slope term?  Use the model to predict egg prices for the next 28 years (the time series ends in 1993, so this will give us a prediction for 2021).  What does the model predict will be the price of eggs in 2021? What does this tell us about the accuracy of the model?

I know this means to have a HoltWinters with `alpha = 1`, `beta = gamma = False`.  However, I do not understand what is meant by the slope term.

Comment: I think it would be better to post one question at a time.

Comment: "Fit a random walk to a time series" does not have a unique meaning. I can think of a couple of ways of doing something which matches that description. Surely the textbook which contains this exercise has a discussion of what it means when it uses that phrase. In any event, this seems like it is more of a statistics question than a programming question. [statistics.se] might be a better place to ask.